# Comparing two email address lists anonymously

Tags: email, hash, comparison

Given two lists:

**Company A:**

user1@example.com

user2@example.com

user3@example.com

user4@example.com

**Company B:**

user2@example.com

user4@example.com

user5@example.com

Is there a way to anonymously compare them to get the number of email addresses in common (i.e., 2) without either company knowing which addresses were the ones in common?

**Background:**

Let's say that company A and company B want to know what portion of their userbase is common. For simplicity, they are just going to base it on email address and not concern themselves with people who use multiple addresses or different address variations (user+misc@example.com).

For the sake of privacy, neither company can give the other the plain list of email addresses. If they used the same simple hash, e.g. MD5, each company could easily know which members were in common (not desired). If they used a hash salted with a company specific secret, the addresses wouldn't be comparable any longer so the question couldn't be answered.

Is there some trick using key encryption or some other mathematical way to accomplish what I'm looking to do?

Comment: you could hire a 3rd party :-) [not a joke, that's what CA's are all about]

Comment: if 2 companies are not ready to share details how can they share it with a 3rd party which may benifit by getting details of both and if it is of no use to 3rd party , it can even spread them in market benifitting others ?

Comment: Thanks for the other non-accepted answers and comments about making this less of a technical problem by getting a third party to do the comparison. That's definitely a possible way to go, but it can lead to additional business side complications. Razvan's answer is what I was looking for on the technical side. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this question could be understood better in the realm of cryptography.

It is a problem of [secure multi-party computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_multi-party_computation).

I'm not aware of any bullet proof solution for this problem but I can think of the following:

1. Choose a commutative hash function (`H`):

   `H(H(string, seed1), seed2) = H(H(string, seed2), seed1)`
2. Each party (Company A and Company B) has to choose a secret seed:

   `SEED_A`, `SEED_B`
3. Company A hashes all email addresses using `SEED_A`, Company B hashes all email addresses using `SEED_B`.
4. They interchange the hashes.
5. Each company applies the hash function again on the set received from the opposing party.
6. At this point the data should already be garbled and the companies should not be able to recognize their own email addresses (since they've been already hashed twice - the second time with an unknown key).
7. All the email addresses should be laid out openly and those that have the same hash should be counted as the email addresses that belong to both companies (except that neither company can tell the source of the hash).

This is the theory. Hopefully I didn't miss anything and there are no flaws in the algorithm.

As for the implementation, here's the most trivial PHP script that I could come with:

```
$a = array("user1@example.com", "user2@example.com", "user3@example.com", "user4@example.com");
$b = array("user2@example.com", "user4@example.com", "user5@example.com");

function enc($str, $seed) {
    for ($i = strlen($str) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $str[$i] = $str[$i] ^ $seed[$i % strlen($seed)];
    }
    
    return $str;
}

/* Company A */
$hashesForB = array();
$SEED_A = 'SALT FOR COMPANY A';

foreach ($a as $address) {
    $hashesForB[] = enc($address, $SEED_A);
}

/* Company B */
$hashesForA = array();
$SALT_B = 'THIS IS THE SALT FOR COMPANY B';

foreach ($b as $address) {
    $hashesForA[] = enc($address, $SALT_B);
}

/* Company A */
$hashesForB_2 = array();

foreach ($hashesForA as $hash) {
    $hashesForB_2[] = enc($hash, $SEED_A);
}

/* Company B */
$hashesForA_2 = array();

foreach ($hashesForB as $hash) {
    $hashesForA_2[] = enc($hash, $SALT_B);
}

$common = count(array_intersect($hashesForA_2, $hashesForB_2));

print $common; // it will output 2
```

[Click here for the DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jbw-736)

As you can see in the code above, I used the XOR algorithm for (pseudo) hashing (actually, any addition based hash function should do the job).

Obviously, this is not the best choice for many reasons:

- XOR will return the original input upon a new call with the same salt
- the entropy is not the best you could hope for
- the data is not truncated

Still, you could implement your own hashing function using the suggestions [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/multiple-hash-functions-that-work-in-either-nesting), [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6197/commutativity-of-keyed-hashes), [here](http://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-practical-commutative-hash-functions) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191020/commutative-accumulator-based-function-for-calculating-a-digest-of-multiple-has).

Comment: What a fantastic answer, Razvan! That's kind of the path that I had been thinking of, with each company applying their own secret to the data, but I was stuck on the hashing part, having come up with only a crude addition based encoding based on the ORD() of the characters. This is much better and I'll explore those very helpful links as well.

Comment: @Razvan how can we come up with a commutative seed pair without somebody somewhere knowing both seeds?

Comment: You can check the 4 links that I mentioned at the bottom. Basically, you can take any commutative mathematical operation and it will do the trick. The simplest one could be multiplication (see the 3rd link). Eg: email * seed1 * seed2 = email * seed2 * seed1.

Answer (score 0):

Is the privacy concern that privacy agreement prohibit sharing of email addresses?  or is it a competitive concern?

If you just want to get an idea of percentage of overlap, then I'd think a simple encoding of the email addresses might work.  For example, de-dupe each list, Base64 encode each email address, then run the comparison to get overlap, then report on the numbers.

A simple NDA could make this a less technical problem.

Answer (score -1):

It depends the language you want to use.

In python, you could use this script :

```
listA = ('user1@example.com', 'user2@example.com', 'user3@example.com')
listB = ('user1@example.com', 'user2@example.com')

result = [x for x in listA if x in listB]
print(len(result))
```

For security, you could host this script in an external server where both companies just can put in their lists and then check the result.